# Google play console remove app from Publishing overview

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Google play has removed my app from production. I have made some changes and want to upload a new version to `Internal testing`.

In the `Publishing overview` section I can see both versions. The old version in the production and the new fixed version in internal testing.

I want to `Send for review` my new version, but I don't want to send my old version.

[image]

How to remove the old version from the `Publishing overview`? Can I specify to review only the new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have contacted Google development support:

> Unfortunately, we cannot deactivate the non-compliant version on your behalf. **You will need to release a new compliant APK on the production track in order to deactivate the non-compliant APK**. We apologize for the inconvenience this has caused.

Answer (score 4):

You can promote your `internal testing` version to `production` with 1% users rollout. In that way, most users won't face the new version, and you will be able to override the old version review.

Steps:

- go to Google Play console
- select `Internal testing` from left menu
- select `Promote release` dropdown menu
- click on `production`
- write "1" in rollout and release

[image]